# update if two fields exists, insert if not (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, insert

This isn't an (exact) duplicate of [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-to-table-or-update-if-exists-mysql) so I'Ve started a new one.

I have this table (ID is primary and auto increment)

```
ID | mykey | myfoo | mybar
============================
 1 | 1.1   | abc   | 123
 2 | 1.1.1 | def   | 456
 3 | 1.2   | abc   | 789
 4 | 1.1   | ghi   | 999
```

I would like to UPDATE row 1 with mybar = "333" only if mykey = '1.1' **AND** myfoo = 'abc'

If either mykey != '1.1' **OR** myfoo != 'abc' I would like to INSERT an new row.

Is this possible with one statement?

Comment: Why don't you add a unique key on `(mykey, myfoo)` and then use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` solution?

Comment: 'mykey' can have the same value one than once, same is with 'myfoo'

Comment: The unique key only applies to the combination of both.

Comment: Thanks.I didn't know that and it was answered below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A unique index in MySQL does not have to be on a single column. You can add a UNIQUE index on multiple columns simply by specifying more columns in your `ALTER TABLE..ADD UNIQUE` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD UNIQUE (
    mykey,
    myfoo
);
```

Now you can use a regular `INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY` statement.

[**SQLFiddle DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43a5d/1/0) (*note that the multiple repeated values are not added - all others are*)

**Note**:

If either is NULL, it will **not** be counted as unique. `mykey` being 'bar' and `myfoo` being NULL could be added to infinity even though they have the "same" values (NULL isn't really a value).

Comment: Thanks! never thought this is possible :)

Comment: The SQLFiddle demo seems to be demonstrating that duplicate values are ignored. The answer is correct but the demo would be better if it showed `INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY` in action.